# Python Classes Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Receiving traceback error.

> NameError: name 'env_prj_fmt' is not defined

Don't understand why CreateApplication not accepting global.

How to correct the method to pass from CreateConfig to CreateApplication

```py
class Application():

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.CreateConfig()

    def CreateConfig(self):
        self.prj_arc = 'PRJ_ARC'
        self.prj_exe = '.exe'
        self.prj_fmt = self.prj_arc + self.prj_exe
        self.cfg_ico = '.ico'
        self.cnf_ico = self.prj_arc + self.cfg_ico

        global env_prj_fmt
        env_prj_fmt = self.prj_fmt        
        global env_cnf_ico
        env_cnf_ico = self.cnf_ico

def CreateApplication():

    # Application()        # CreateConfig()     > requires 1 positional
                           # CreateConfig(self) > self undefined
    # global env_prj_fmt 
    root = env_prj_fmt
    print(root)

    # global env_cnf_ico
    icon = env_cnf_ico
    print(icon)

    # app = Application(root)
    # app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CreateApplication()
```

Comment: You never called `CreateConfig()` (which would have required you to first create an instance of `Application`).  The global variables it defines therefore never came into existence.

Comment: @jasonharper is this what you meant? Invoking Application here works. However it will invoke two windows Tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the variable as `global` in every scope you intend to use it as such:

```py
def CreateApplication(): 
    global env_prj_fmt # Here
    root = env_prj_fmt # self.cnf_ico
    print(root)
    global env_cnf_ico # This one too
    icon = env_cnf_ico # self.prj_fmt
    print(icon)
```